# Based on dropdown selection how to display the current scope value in the table in angular js

Tags: angularjs

**Requirement**: When i go to the page default data loading,(default data available in scope) but when i select the particular syllabus i need to display only the selected syllabus data so i cleared the scope.quizdata and assigned the filtered data to the scope.quizdata.Now scope value is as expected for by requirement but its not reflecting in the display (default data displaying but i need filtered data)

```
$scope.filterSyllabus = function () {
            var data = $scope.quizdata
        
            $scope.quizdata = [];
          
            var getsyllabuslistarray = [];
            if (data.length > 0) {
                 getsyllabuslistarray = data.filter((item) => {
                    if ($scope.assessment.sellectedSyllabusName.length > 0) {
                        if (item.syllabus_id == $scope.assessment.sellectedSyllabusName[0].id) {
                            return item;
                        }
                    }else{
                       return $scope.originalQuizData;
                    }
                });
               
                $scope.quizdata = getsyllabuslistarray             
            }
        }




<div class="box box-solid " ng-class="flashback" ng-if="quizdata">
    <div class="box-body">
        <flash-message duration="5000" show-close="true" on-dismiss="myCallback(flash);">
        </flash-message>
        <loading></loading>
        <!-- Color Picker -->
        <div ng-class="quizlistmobile">
            <table class="table table-bordered bordered table-striped table-condensed datatable" ng-if="quizdata" datatable="ng" ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="dataTableOpt">
                <p>{{quizdata}}</p>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.No.</th>
                        <th>syllabus</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-if="n.id!=1" ng-repeat="n in quizdata">
                        <td class="rowquiz">{{$index+1}}</td>
                        <td class="rowquiz">{{ n.syllabus_id }}</td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- /.form group -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning bound variables can break the binding causing bound data to stop updating. When working with arrays that you want to reset, first empty then push new values in. This preserves the object reference thus the watched scope member.

```
$scope.filterSyllabus = function () {
    const filterId = $scope.assessment?.selectedSyllabusName[0]?.id;
    if (filterId && data.length > 0) {
        const filteredData = $scope.quizdata.filter((item) => {
            if (item.syllabus_id == filterId) {
                return item;
            }
        });
        $scope.quizdata.length = 0;
        $scope.quizdata.push(...filteredData);        
    }
}
```

I made a couple assumptions and corrections:

1. `sellectedSyllabusName` was a typo of `selectedSyllabusName`
2. `filterId` should be a positive, non-zero integer
3. an invalid `filterId` should not filter